# How to pass a Parameterized Command to a CommandContributionItem

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

Using Eclipse and SWT I am currently trying to get a `CommandContributionItem` (CCI) as a `Button` into a `ViewPart` with two text fields. When I push the button my `ParameterizedCommand` should be called using the current text values of the text fields as parameters.

I was able to pass the initial values of the text fields to the CCI like that:

```java
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    text = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

    text_1 = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    text_1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("myString", text.getText());
    params.put("mySecondString", text_1.getText());

    CommandContributionItemParameter p = new CommandContributionItemParameter(getSite(),
            "commandSyso","com.voo.example.commandparameter.simple.sysoCommand",  CommandContributionItem.STYLE_PUSH);
    p.label = "My Label";
    p.parameters = params;
    CommandContributionItem item = new CommandContributionItem(p);
    item.fill(parent);
}
```

But it is a static one-time pass. Is there a way to update this dynamically every time the CCI is called?

Comment: Could you please stop messing with edits ? The only edit you're doing is changing one tag for another very similar... That doesn't improve the questions, please stop this

Comment: @Liarez the tags are not similar at all. The cdo tag is about a collaborative modeling framework, the cdo.message tag is about prior OLE messaging and an API. If I search for a tag and find 60+% unrelated stuff, it's not working at all. Not for me and not for the people who might want help. But I think you got a point there. The tag "CDO" is misleading. Maybe it should be changed to something like "cdo.modeling" or "emf.cdo" to make it distinct to cdo.messaging. I'll have a look where I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CommandContributionItem` parameters are static in nature.  You can't modify them, only create a new instance of `CommandContributionItem`.

When working with commands, implementation of `IHandler` should look for the current selection using the `ExecutionEvent.getApplicationContext()`.  If it is an `IEvaluationContext`, the selection can be retrieved using `org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil`

But in your example, you would need some way to supply the values of your 2 text fields to the framework, either by implementing an `ISelectionProvider`, an `ISourceProvider` (where you could provide each text field under a new name), or by having your handler check for your `IViewPart` and then access the information through accessors.

Comment: Checking the IViewPart from the Handler would make the advantage of the ParameterizedCommand obsolete, if I understood it corretly. I was already able to use the ParameterizedCommand with a SWT Button. And I did implemented a CCI with a Command/Handler which read from my IViewPartt.
I was just hoping that there was a nice and easy solution for this that I missed. 
But I will try the ISourceProvider solution next. This looks like it will work for me. Thank you.